# VF Page for slot Freezing

Tags: visualforce

I have added an VF page on event for slot Freezing. Following is the code.
When i click on Freeze it should change the color to red and the Day and "AM or PM or All day" data should be saved in some field. How can we do this.

```
​<apex:page StandardController="Event">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Appointments">
     <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Days</th>
    <th>AM</th>
    <th>PM</th>
    <th>All Days</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><Strong>Monday</Strong></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td></tr>
 <tr>
    <td><Strong>Tuesday</Strong></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><Strong>Wednesday</Strong></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><Strong>Thurday</Strong></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><Strong>Friday</Strong></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td>
    <td><a href="#Freeze">Freeze</a></td></tr>
</table>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SF.SE Sana. There's much you've not told us to really be able to help you. From your description, you're either going to need custom JS and very likely a controller extension on `Event`.

The color change can be easily handled using CSS by assigning a different CSS class to that table cell "onClick" that changes the cell's background color to red. Once you do that, you can disable the "onClick" to change it back or allow it to "toggle" between the two if using jQuery.

How are you planning to store the data? Do you have custom fields on Event? If not, are they `startDateTime` for each slot along with `endDateTime`? If the latter, the easiest way to do this would be using `selectOptions` and an `ActionMethod` that fires "onClick" over an `ActionRegion` with `ActionSupport`. The option (slot) that's selected would then be saved and your method would convert it to both a `startDateTime` and an `endDateTime`.

That's one approach of many that you could take. Alternatively, you could put an ActionFunction that fires "onclick" as part of each cell definition which I'd expect to be more tedious, but might be helpful if you use JS/JQuery for the change in CSS; something you should also be able to do with Ajax.

Use the search box at the top right of the page to find posts on selectOption if you need to find examples with code. Also refer to the Visualforce Developer's Guide, particularly the [SelectOption Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm).